# Lag value with dates

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I am studying the price of a product along time. I have daily data with some missing info at random.

See here a minimal example where info for the 4th of January is missing:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

mockData <- data.table(timeStamp=c(ymd("20180101"), ymd("20180102"), ymd("20180103"), ymd("20180105")),
                       price=c(10,15,12,11))
```

I want to add the lagged price to my `data.table` but if the previous day is missing, I want a `NA` instead of the closest day with info.

I explain myself:

If I use the `shift` function:

`mockData[, lag_price:=shift(price,type="lag")]`

I get:

```
structure(list(timeStamp = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17534, 17536
), class = "Date"), price = c(10, 15, 12, 11), lag_price = c(NA, 
                                                             10, 15, 12)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                             "data.frame"))
```

But what I really want is this:

```
structure(list(timeStamp = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17534, 17536
), class = "Date"), price = c(10, 15, 12, 11), lag_price = c(NA, 
                                                             10, 15, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                             "data.frame"))
```

I fell more comfortable using `data.table` but I will work with `data.frame`, `dplyr` and `tidyverse` if required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an `ifelse` statement to check for consecutive days

```
mockData[, lag_price := ifelse(timeStamp - shift(timeStamp) == 1, shift(price), NA)]
#    timeStamp price lag_price
#1: 2018-01-01    10        NA
#2: 2018-01-02    15        10
#3: 2018-01-03    12        15
#4: 2018-01-05    11        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mockData[, v := 
  data.table(timeStamp = timeStamp + 1, price)[.SD, on=.(timeStamp), x.price]
]

    timeStamp price  v
1: 2018-01-01    10 NA
2: 2018-01-02    15 10
3: 2018-01-03    12 15
4: 2018-01-05    11 NA
```

This uses a table with `(timeStamp + 1, price)` for an update join.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand out the dates and then `lag`price. In this strategy, you also have the option of introducing a filter in the pipeline to take out dates you don't want.

```
data.frame(timeStamp = seq(min(mockData$timeStamp), max(mockData$timeStamp), by = 1)) %>%
  # you could add a further filter in here to clean out dates you don't want
  left_join(., mockData, by = "timeStamp") %>%
  mutate(lag_price = lag(price)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(all_dates)) %>%
  select(-all_dates)
```